# Some questions about the definition of differentiability in multivariable Calculus.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A function $f:R^n \rightarrow R^m$ is differentiable with respect to $\vec v$ at $\vec x_o$ if there exists a Linear transformation $L:R^n \rightarrow R^m$ such that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\vec x_o + h \hat v) - f(\vec x_0) - L(h \hat v)}{h}=0$$

1) Is the above definition correct?

2) Is the linear transformation also the derivative at $x_o$ or is it just proof that the derivative exists but the derivative isn't necessarily that linear transformation?

3) If 2) is true, Is the derivative point $\vec x_o$ equal to $L(\hat v)$ or $L(\vec x_o)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a correct definition only of  *directional*  or *Gateaux* differentiability of $f$ at $x_0$.  If $n>1$ what is usually meant by differentiability is *strong* or *Frechet* differentiability, which requires the convergence in your limit to be *uniform* on bounded sets of $\hat v$.
2. Yes: the derivative at $x_0$ is that linear transformation $L$.
3. I don't understand your 3d question.  The derivative of $f$ at $x_0$, which is sometimes denoted $Df_{x_0}$ or $f'(x_0)$, is the linear transformation that maps $\hat v$ to $L(\hat v) = f'(x_0) \hat v$, which shows up, for instance, in the Taylor (or linearization) expansions $$f(x_0+h\hat v) = f(x_0) + h f'(x_0)  \hat v + o(h)$$
   (for fixed $\hat v$, for directionally differential $f$) 
   and $$f(x_0 + v) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) v + o(\|v\|)$$ for Frechet differentiable $f$.

Comment: I think I worded the question incorrectly. What I meant to ask was that when we get a Linear transformation $L$ for that point $x_o$, for example at point $x_o$ we get the Linear transformation $L(x)=mx$ then what is the slope at $x_o$, $m\vec x_o$ or $m\hat v$

Comment: The slope is $m$.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me a lot.